# How to clean build folder in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, build

It seems that the shortcut to "Clean Build Folder" in Xcode 5 has disappeared! Command+Option+Shift+K doesn't work anymore. Anyone got the new shortcut?

Comment: Did you look at the shortcut shown next to "Clean" on the "Product" menu?

Comment: I was not talking about the "Clean" but the "Build Clean" where it deletes the builds/ folders.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of Xcode 7, this feature is back. Press **Command**+**Option**+**Shift**+**K**.

Or from the menu -> **Product**, press Option on your keyboard and you'll see **Clean Build Folder...**

Answer (score 6):

It's what you set it to via the "Key Bindings" section in your Xcode preferences.

[image]

For me, it's shift-command-K.

Comment: Ok! The Clean Build Folder is what I want. But it seems the shortcut doesn't work and I'm not able to modify it! Option-Shift-Command-K does not do anything :(

Answer (score 6):

XCode -> Product -> Clean

With the shortcut Shift-Cmd-K (no option key).