# iOS 11.0 : Simulator not showing app icon

Tags: icons, ios11, xcode9

I am working on quiz app. I have added app icons for all size and also mention app icon in project settings but i haven't find what is wrong with the project.

[image]

i have also mention path in target.

[image]

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437560/my-ios-app-is-not-showing-app-icon-in-simulator