# React Native iOS app icon doesn’t show up

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, cross-platform

I am using XCode 12 and I was trying to archive the iOS app. The app runs completely fine with no error as such but the app icon doesn’t show up. Also there are no issues at all with the app assets. Just the icon doesn’t show up.

I tried all the possible ways like changing codes in the pod file as suggested here:

[My iOS app is not showing App Icon in Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437560/my-ios-app-is-not-showing-app-icon-in-simulator/46349476)

And also removing the existing icons and adding them again. Besides, I also tried to remove the flipper and archive.

All of these things didn’t yield me the expected results.

Could anyone help me with this? I have been stuck with this for over a week now. Expecting some early suggestions. Thanks in advance.[The screenshot of the same is linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmasW.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue previously. And got to know that there is something broken with images in the react-native build with iOS 12.

Please try to build it with Xcode 11 version and it will work.

Also, you can refer to Facebook/react-native page from the below link as well to have a clear idea of this.

[Facebook/react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279)

Comment: initially while taking a build it worked, it happened while i was taking the recent build.

Comment: I don’t think downgrading it is a feasible option anyways.

Comment: Also the one you linked here in the react-native issues talks about the images but i have issue with the app icon not with rendering any image.

Comment: The same goes for icons also. I have tried it myself. If you can give it a try you will understand what I am trying to say. @DibyajyotiMishra